# How do you unlock each video in MGS3's Demo Theater?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-hd-collection, metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater

How do I unlock each of the alternate videos for *Metal Gear Solid 3's* "DEMO THEATER"? There seems to be a real lack of information online about it! :(

Thanks for any SPECIFIC explanations that go through each alternate video and how you unlock them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, you have to play through the game at least four times. The alternate scenes are:

When you're fighting The End, and your final duel with Ocelot.

THE END:

1. Beat him normally.
2. Beat him by saving, quitting out, and then setting your clock several weeks forward.

There's also:

1. Letting your stamina drain down.
2. Saving, quitting out, and setting your system clock forward a day.

OCELOT:

1. Pick the left gun, shoot Ocelot.
2. Pick the left gun, miss Ocelot.
3. Pick the left gun, don't fire.
4. Pick the right gun.

When you've unlocked all the of the videos in DEMO THEATER, you get access to the PEEP SHOW. Which is all the scenes in the game with semi-nudity.

Comment: You could also get the sniper right after the river scene after fighting the Pain, and killing The End then and there. You'll encounter sentrys in the forest. Don't know if it unlocks anything though.